# Someone who wants to have important friends?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, epithet-requests

Is there a word for a person who acts a certain way to become friends with others of a higher or more important social status? Someone who will act falsely to impress others for their own gain (i.e to then show off about it to "lesser" people, in a "look who i'm friends with" style)?

Comment: Perhaps *Social climber*. Welcome, and please take the [tour]. Single word requests require an example sentence with a fill-in-the-blank format. Please edit your question, or it will probably get closed shortly.

Answer (score 15):

**Sycophant** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sycophant)

> *noun* a person who praises powerful people in order to get their approval; a servile self-seeking flatterer
>   *"when her career was riding high, the self-deluded actress often mistook sycophants for true friends"*

Comment: Hi Seymore, welcome to English Language & Usage. You're halfway to a good answer! This site is a bit different from other Q&A sites: brief suggestions are discouraged, in favour of a detailed answer explaining why it is correct - preferably by quoting a reference and/or linking to a source (eg a dictionary definition). For help writing a good answer, see [Answer]. For more information about how EL&U works, please take the **[Tour]**. You can add more detail to your answer by clicking on the [edit] link. :-)

Comment: I have added a dictionary definition. Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

> **Snob** \Snob\, n. [Icel. sn[=a]pr a dolt, impostor, charlatan. Cf.
>        {*Snub*}.]
>        1. A vulgar person who affects to be better, richer, or more
>           fashionable, than he really is; a vulgar upstart; one who
>           apes his superiors. --*Thackeray*.
>           [1913 Webster]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Pretentious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretentious) to describe such a person.

> having or showing the unpleasant quality of people who want to be
>   regarded as more impressive, successful, or important than they really
>   are

Used in a sentence:

> John used to be an alright person, but ever since he started hanging around with Roger he's started acting quite *pretentious*.